# In .Net Core API, ModelState.IsValid is not catching Required parameters

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

.Net Core 3.1 API.  I've read a lot of threads that ask about why ModelState.IsValid isn't working as expected. Most are for web pages and not API's. And the ones I have found about API's either don't exactly apply or didn't lead me to an understanding.

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Prop1 is required.")]
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }

    public List<int> IntList { get; set; }
}
```

And I have an API endpoint:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class FooBarController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] MyModel request)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        // do stuff

        return Ok(results);

    }
}
```

Now, in Postman, if I pass this as the body, it works as expected:

```
{ "Prop1": 1001}
```

But if I pass this, I would expect an error of `Prop1 is required.` to be thrown:

```
{ "Prop2": 1001}
```

However, there is no error. The model is still valid and I just get back an empty set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integers have a default value of 0, therefore, once initialized, the value of prop1 will be 0, therefore it passes the `[Required]` test.   If you make prop1 nullable, then required should catch if it is missing.

Or, if you don't want your property to be nullable, you can add a range validator:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Prop1 is required.")]
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Prop1 must be greater than 0.")]
public int Prop1 { get; set; }
```

On a project last year, I created an attribute that was something like `[NotNullOrDefault]` which would work with integers being 0, or strings being null, or anything else not having it's default value.

Comment: Ah! Ok! I should have realized that. Actually I don't want the prop to be nullable. But I added a Range validator as well, and that did the trick. `[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Prop1 must be greater than 0.")]`  If you can add that to your answer, I'll mark it as correct.